# problems in body and footer

Tags: html, css

there is a strange white line in my screen.
It's possible to see the line in jsfiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/fWq3c/3/
My real screen image is available here:
http://postimage.org/image/w4jcveyyv/f0779d0b/

The strange thing is that my body is no in all the screen.

In my code, the div #tudo is inside body. But in result, it appears that #tudo expand beyond body.

```
    <body>
    <div id="tudo">
        <div id="topo_login"></div>
        <div id="conteudo_login">
            @RenderBody() 
        </div>
        <div class="limpar"></div>
        <div id="rodape2"></div>            
        <div id="rodape"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That line appears because the background image `http://s15.postimage.org/sjog2gpff/Fundo.png` is having a border at the bottom of white color. Change/edit this image and try again.

Comment: In fact, the image should be in all the page. Is there a way to put this background image in all screen?

Comment: I've put this image on body element because I want the image appear in all the screeen to build a gradient background. But the incredible result was that the body is not on all screen.

Comment: I'm almost there. I've just understood that the problem is that my image is not resizing. http://jsfiddle.net/fWq3c/4/

Comment: On IE8 it works well, but not in chrome version 19.0.1084.56 m

Comment: You wish to extend the image all the way down to as high the page is?